# news part of android application

Tags: java, android, client-server

I need to add news part to my android application.
For example some application shows a notification that says the new version is available or our new product has been released. Some application shows this once and some of the shows each time the Internet is available.
Is there a class for server and client side of this parts?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

While working with Google Playstore, you can achieve this by updating your app version in the manifest file before publishing the updated apk build. Google Playstore will show timely alerts to the user saying "App needs to be updated", redirecting them to the Google Playstore link.

`android:versionName="2.0"`

Also you can call one of your webservice, within the application which checks the existing app version and latest app version. If the app needs to be updated it redirects to the same Google Playstore link.